# D'où vient l'expression "en derrière de"?

Tags: régionalismes

J'ai entendu plusieurs fois l'expression "en derrière de XXX" (pour dire, je pense, "derrière XXX"). Savez-vous d'où elle vient ?

Comment: : : De Suisse ?

Comment: L'inconnu des dicos « En derrière de X. », soit  ← « En *arrière* de X. », soit ← « *Par-derrière* X. » (sans *de*), où vos oreilles ouïrent-elles une telle tournure vernaculaire ?

Answer (score 3):

Étymologiquement, les mots *derrière* et *arrière* viennent du latin *[retro](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/retro#Latin)*, un adverbe qui veut dire « à l'arrière », « vers l'arrière » et d'autres sens voisins. En ancien français, *retro* a évolué en *[riere](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/riere#Old_French)/[rere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rere#Old_French)* (et autres variantes). L'adverbe *riere* était souvent utilisé comme préposition, et le [dictionnaire de Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/riere) (qui couvre l'ancien et le moyen français, du 9<sup>e</sup> au 15<sup>e</sup>) le cite essentiellement comme préposition.

L'adverbe *retro* était utilisé en latin populaire dans des constructions comme *ad retro* ou *de retro* qui ont donné *a riere* et *de riere* en ancien français. Ces constructions ont donné les mots *arrière* et *derrière* en français moderne, tandis que *riere* tout seul s'est perdu.

Ces mots ont probablement évolué sous l'influence de leurs antonymes *[avant](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avant)* et *[devant](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/devant)*. Si *devant* vient de *de* + *avant*, le mot *avant* avait déjà son préfixe *a* en latin. Ce préfixe vient du préfixe *ab-*, mais c'était déjà un seul mot en ancien français et pas une locution en deux mots. L'absence de <strike>*vant*</strike> a dû contribuer à la perte de *riere*.

En moyen français, les mots *[arrière](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/arriere)*, *[derrière](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/deriere)*, *[avant](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/avant)* et *[devant](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/devant)* ont évolué pour devenir aussi des noms. Voici quelques exemples cités par Godefroy :

> Mettre ma valeur au derriere. ([Christine de Pizan](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christine_de_Pizan), *Le Livre du chemin de loc estude*, 1403)

> Le derriere d'un chevreul (1459)

> Ça en arrere (= jadis)

> Si s'umelie en son devant ([Guillaume Le Clerc de Normandie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_Le_Clerc_de_Normandie), *Bestiaire divin*, 1210)

Puisque *derrière* et compagnie étaient désormais des noms, il fallait une préposition pour les utiliser comme locution adverbiale ou prépositionnelle. Mais comme c'étaient en fait encore des adverbes, la préposition n'était pas obligatoire. Ceci explique sans doute la diversité des locutions prépositionnelles qu'on a pu rencontrer en français et qui existe encore en français moderne : *à l'arrière de*, *en arrière de*, *derrière*, *par derrière de* (plus l'adverbe *par derrière* en fait), *au devant de* (*au derrière (de)* est beaucoup plus rare)...

La locution *en derriere* est d'usage relativement courant en moyen français. [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/derri%C3%A8re) donne plusieurs citations :

> La vieille et sa fille orent pourparlé en derriere. ([*Berthe aux grands pieds*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berthe_aux_grands_pieds_(po%C3%A8me)*), v. 1273)

> Là ne sunt pas li tesmong oy en derriere des parties. ([Philippe de Beaumanoir](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_de_Beaumanoir_(1250-1296)), *[Coutumes de Beauvaisis](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coutumes_de_Beauvaisis)*, v. 1283)

> Nos yeulx ne veoient rien en derriere : nous nous mocquons de nous sur le subject de nostre voisin; … ([Montaigne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_de_Montaigne), *Essais*, v. 1580)

Le *Dictionnaire universel* de Furetière (1690) [donne le sens](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/derriere) :

> On dit aussi populairement, Il a fait telle chose en derriere de moy, pour dire, Il me l'a voulu cacher.

En français moderne, on parle de faire quelque chose « dans le dos de quelqu'un » ou « derrière le dos de quelqu'un ». Le *[Dictionnaire de patois normand](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Dictionnaire_de_patois_normand/r5CAEwRNHdsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22en+derri%C3%A8re%22&pg=PA239&printsec=frontcover)* (Henri Moisy, 1887) définit aussi « en derrière (de) » comme « en arrière (de) » comme ayant plus spécialement ce sens. C'est le sens de la plupart des citations de Littré, mais pas celui chez Montaigne, qui l'utilise dans le sens littéral (nos yeux ne voient que ce qui est devant eux, et pas nous-mêmes, qui sommes derrière nos yeux).

La locution « en derrière » n'est plus du français standard au 21<sup>e</sup> siècle. Il est possible qu'elle soit encore standard dans certaines régions, mais je ne l'ai jamais rencontrée (y compris en Normandie où j'ai vécu). J'ai tout de même trouvé quelques occurrences modernes sur le web, sans localisation géographique particulière, dans le sens littéral où l'expression habituelle serait « à l'arrière de » ou simplement « derrière ».

> [il y' a un petit réservoir et un tuyau en plastique en derrière de l'appareil](https://forums.futura-sciences.com/depannage/897611-nettoyeur-haute-pression-lavor-extra-20-a.html)

> [En derrière de l'antenne on voit leurs yeux rouges.](http://www.microscopies.com/DOSSIERS/Magazine/Articles/WD-CLE%20BDELLOIDEA/BD%20ARTICLE%201.htm)

> [Ajouter un renvoi […] en derrière de page](https://www.legalplace.fr/guides/pv-assemblee-generale/) *(l'expression consacrée est « au dos [de la page] »)*

> [Stationnement gratuit en derrière de la structure](https://pro.appines.fr/annonces/masseur-kinesitherapeute/remplacement/toutes-regions/toutes-villes/etablissement/offre-de-remplacement-long)

Comment: « En derrière de page » resté dans la tradition législative a dû échapper à la rénovation des textes. *Derrière* intuitivement est plus facilement compréhensible que le concept “au verso” ; en revanche la suppression de l'article est intéressante et cohérente avec ce qui précède « Ajouter un renvoi ***en bas de page***, *en marge* ou ***en derrière de page*** ; », ce qui exclus “au dos de *la* page”, ce doit être une des très rares circonstances de l'emploi de *en derrière de*. Les autres exemples sont plutôt du ressort des dérives du langage familier. Belle réponse parfaitement documentée :-)

Comment: @Personne Google ne trouve qu'une seule page (et deux copies) contenant “en derrière de page”. Ce n'est pas une survivance de la langue juridique, c'est juste une personne qui a écrit ça.